# Grails Mongdb many-to-one GORM not loading parent

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm, gorm-mongodb

We have a simple many-to-one relation using grails and mongodb:

```
class GrupoConcesiones {
    ObjectId id
    String nombre
}

class Concesion {

    ObjectId id
    String nombre
    GrupoConcesiones grupo

    Set<Marca> marcas
    static hasMany = [
        marcas: Marca
    ]

    static belongsTo = [
        GrupoConcesiones
    ]

}
```

If I query Concesion domain object, the group inside it only has the id field:

Concesion c = Concesion.list()[0]

- c.grupo -> GrupoConcesiones object
- c.grupo.id -> ObjectId("53ce42c12cdc09e604d9be35")
- c.group.nombre -> null

The group has the property name in mongodb correctly.

I've tried adding the hasMany to GrupoConcesiones, removing the belongsTo... all options.

Does grails-mongodb support read an entire parent object from the child with belongsTo?

Comment: how your collections look like?

Comment: Should that read `c.grupo.nombre` ?

Comment: With postgresql the parent relation like c.group is loaded lazy when access to c.group.nombre but with mongodb not or I don't know how I can do it

Comment: The mongodb object has "group": ObjectId("53cf64c82cdcdac6fc4a10df")